# SyntaxError:unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: syntax-error

I am new to programming in trying to make a simple text based video game. my first goal was to make an introduction which was just me coding input ('...') after input to make a short intro / plot overview

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: We can't help at all unless we know what language, see your code, and have the exact error.

Comment: @Linuxios  sorry I'm writing code in python. I can't put any pics until I get 10 reputations and I am new to stack overflow

Comment: Not pictures. We need to see the code.